# Is there a pandas function to transpose a data frame to create a separate column for each unique value of an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose, pivottable.js

I want to change my dataframe into a format that I can use for a simple analysis. Currently, my dataframe is in the following format:

```
 Carrier | Service | Weight | Area | Charge
   A     |   GRND  |  1     |  2   | $5.0
   A     |   GRND  |  2     |  2   | $6.0
   A     |   GRND  |  3     |  2   | $7.0
   B     |   GRND  |  1     |  2   | $5.5
   B     |   GRND  |  3     |  2   | $6.9
```

I would like to transpose my data into the following format:

```
  Service | Weight | Area | CarrierA_Charge | CarrierB_Charge
   GRND   |  1     |  2   |      $5.0       |   $5.5
   GRND   |  2     |  2   |      $6.0       |   NA
   GRND   |  3     |  2   |      $7.0       |   $6.9
```

Ultimately, my goal is to create a column that gives me the carrier with minimum charge for each unique combination of Service, Weigh, Area like below:

```
  Service | Weight | Area | CarrierA_Charge | CarrierB_Charge | min_charge |min_charge_carrier
   GRND   |  1     |  2   |      $5.0       |   $5.5          |  $5.0      |   A
   GRND   |  2     |  2   |      $6.0       |   NA            |  $6.0      |   A
   GRND   |  3     |  2   |      $7.0       |   $6.9          |  $6.9      |   B
```

Is there a built-in pandas function to use to get to this or how can I write a function in python to achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to do this using the [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) method. Plenty of examples are provided on the docs page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
d = df.set_index(['Service', 'Weight', 'Area', 'Carrier']).Charge.unstack()
d.rename(columns=f'{d.columns.name}{{}}_Charge'.format) \
 .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

  Service  Weight  Area  CarrierA_Charge  CarrierB_Charge
0    GRND       1     2              5.0              5.5
1    GRND       2     2              6.0              NaN
2    GRND       3     2              7.0              6.9
```

---

Slightly different formatting and additional columns

```
d0 = df.set_index(['Service', 'Weight', 'Area', 'Carrier']).Charge.unstack()
d1 = pd.concat(dict(min_charge=d0.min(1), min_charge_carrier=d0.idxmin(1)), axis=1)
fmt = f'{d.columns.name}{{}}_Charge'.format

d0.rename(columns=fmt).join(d1).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

  Service  Weight  Area  NoneA_Charge  NoneB_Charge  min_charge min_charge_carrier
0    GRND       1     2           5.0           5.5         5.0                  A
1    GRND       2     2           6.0           NaN         6.0                  A
2    GRND       3     2           7.0           6.9         6.9                  B
```

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot table approach

```py
# pivot table
pivot = df.pivot_table(columns = 'Carrier', index=['Service', 'Weight', 'Area'], values='Charge',
                       aggfunc = np.min).reset_index()

# rename columns here
```

Answer (score 1):

To fully answer your question including the extra columns:

First we create your pivot and rename your columns accordingly:

### Step 1: pivot and rename

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Service', 'Weight', 'Area'], 
                       columns='Carrier', 
                       values='Charge', 
                       aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))

pivot.columns = [pivot.columns.name + col + '_Charge' for col in pivot.columns]
pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

```
  Service  Weight  Area CarrierA_Charge CarrierB_Charge
0    GRND       1     2            $5.0            $5.5
1    GRND       2     2            $6.0             NaN
2    GRND       3     2            $7.0            $6.9
```

### Step 2 create extra columns:

```
cols = ['CarrierA_Charge', 'CarrierB_Charge']

for col in cols:
    pivot[col] = pivot[col].str.replace('$', '').astype(float)

pivot['min_charge'] = pivot[['CarrierA_Charge', 'CarrierB_Charge']].min(axis=1)

pivot['min_charge_carrier'] = np.where(pivot['min_charge'].eq(pivot['CarrierA_Charge']), 
                                       'A', 'B')
```

---

```
  Service  Weight  Area  CarrierA_Charge  CarrierB_Charge  min_charge min_charge_carrier
0    GRND       1     2              5.0              5.5         5.0                  A
1    GRND       2     2              6.0              NaN         6.0                  A
2    GRND       3     2              7.0              6.9         6.9                  B
```